# I gave you life. What am I?

Tags: riddle

I am lifeless, yet I gave you life.
My contents are gone but are still in the air.
My sides are sweaty, especially in the cold.
When you are done, I am rarely used again.
What am I?

Comment: Did you write this? If not, please provide a source and let us know if it's part of a competition or anything of that nature.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Why don't you take [the tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour)?

Answer (score 7):

Answer:

> Water

I am lifeless, yet I gave you life.

> Water is lifeless but required by all living things to live.

My contents are gone but are still in the air.

> Water evaporates but remains in the air.

My sides are sweaty, especially in the cold.

> Condensation occurs on cold surfaces.

When you are done, I am rarely used again.

> Water that is passed out from the body is rarely used again.

What am I?

> Water.

Answer (score 2):

You may be

> An empty disposable water bottle

I am lifeless, yet I gave you life.

> Lifeless, but held a requirement for life

My contents are gone but are still in the air.

> The water is no longer in the bottle, but water (vapor) is in the air

My sides are sweaty, especially in the cold.

> Condensation on the outside of the bottle when it's cold

When you are done, I am rarely used again.

> Most of the time, disposable water bottles are not reused.  (Though hopefully they are *recycled*...)

Answer (score 2):

My answer:

> Breath

I am lifeless, yet I gave you life:

> Breathing is necessary for life.

My contents are gone but are still in the air:

> When you breathe out, the gases are returned to the air.

My sides are sweaty, especially in the cold:

> Water vapor in breath is visible in the cold.

When you are done, I am rarely used again:

> When you die, you no longer breathe

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps (though there are a couple of things don't *quite* seem to fit) you are

> an oxygen cylinder.

I am lifeless, yet I gave you life.

> It's just a lump of metal. But it might have saved your life, if you had e.g. a respiratory problem that required a dose of pure oxygen.

My contents are gone but are still in the air.

> Probably in the form of carbon dioxide, now.

My sides are sweaty, especially in the cold.

> Condensation. Though this doesn't fit perfectly: you get more condensation on a cold object like an oxygen cylinder when the environment isn't so cold.

When you are done, I am rarely used again.

> Hmm. Are oxygen cylinders usually disposable? [Sometimes](http://www.alliedhpi.com/images/z31-00-0002.pdf).

Another possibility that's closely enough related that I'm putting it in the same answer rather than a different one: you might be

> a CO2 fire extinguisher.

The explanations are all more or less the same, aside from an obvious change to the first one.

Comment: You could propose FPHON gnax with very similar justification.

Comment: True, though the second and third lines are weaker then.